# GeolocationPositionError

Tags: javascript

пишу небольшой пет и пытаюсь получить текущее местоположение, но вылазит след ошибка

```
export async function currentGeoPositionRequest() {
  try {
    const currentPosition = await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => position,
      (e) => console.error(e),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    )
    console.log(currentPosition)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error>>', e)
  }
}
```

[Error] GeolocationPositionError {code: 2, message: "", PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3}

В чем проблема?

Comment: `code: 2` → `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GeolocationPositionError читаем «Не удалось получить геолокацию, поскольку по крайней мере один внутренний источник позиции вернул внутреннюю ошибку»

Comment: от вас всегда максимально дельные советы, я видел это.
А что оно означает?где ошибку искать? Браузеру разрешен доступ к позиции

Answer (score 1):

У меня показывает координаты вот так...

Тут блокирует. Но в браузере код рабочий. Главное дать разрешение на использование геолокации.

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}, err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: поставил галочки на хром, в сафари все заработало...

Comment: @ksa, по поводу ваших правок меток. Не нужно копипастить содержимое других сайтов, это запрещено правилами. Также, краткое описание должно содержать руководство по использованию метки, а не быть фактически полным описанием. Обращайте внимание на причины, по которым ваши правки отклонены.